# Unreal Engine 5 LevelBlueprint fails to build when new project is made

Tags: c++, visual-studio, game-development, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

When I create a new project in Unreal Engine 5 and build the level blueprint, it throws two errors and fails to build:
Output:
[image: Output]

Error List:
[image: Error List]

How could I resolve these two errors so that the file builds successfully?

I tried opening the file locations listed, but found no problem within them. I assume there might be something I am supposed to do before building each time because this happens without changing anything to the initial files.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875)

Comment: Run Visual Studio as admin.

Comment: This could be a problem with hot reload (which is avoided by compiling from the .sln with the editor closed), or a filesystem issue with having the project in a OneDrive folder

Answer (score 0):

close unreal engine editor.
Then compile in visual studio.